# Cannot find symbol using DriverManager.getConnection()

Tags: java, jdbc

I have this code below, where I use DriveManager to manage my database driver.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws SQLException  {
            Connection con = new DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/first-example","SA","");
        }
```

But Im having an error with `.getConnection()`, the error is:

**Cannot find symbol**

**symbol:** class getConnection

**class:** DriveManager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is a `static` method. Remove the `new` keyword

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/first-example","SA","");
```